# calling user control to the mainwindow in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

this issue is regarding how to use context menu, which is created as user control in the main window.
the user control is like..

```
 <UserControl x:Class="contextmenu1.context"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" >
    <UserControl.Resources>

    <ContextMenu x:Key="conmen" >
        <MenuItem Header="Cut" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" >
            <!--<MenuItem.Icon >
            <Image Source="Images/cut.png" Height="20" Width="20" />
        </MenuItem.Icon>-->
        </MenuItem>
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Copy" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14">
            <!--<MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/copy.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>-->
        </MenuItem>
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Paste" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14">
            <!--<MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Images/paste.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>-->
        </MenuItem>
        <Separator />
        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14">

        </MenuItem>
        <Separator />

    </ContextMenu>
    <!--<Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource conmen}"/>
    </Style>-->

   </UserControl.Resources>

  </UserControl>
```

and the mainwindow code is like..

```
 <Window x:Class="contextmenu1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:contextmenu1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
     <Grid>
      <Button x:Name="conbut"  Content="RightClick" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="234,135,0,0"/>



     <dc:context />    
   </Grid>    
  </Window>
```

i included the required namespace, but somehow when i click on the button contextmenu is not appearing,thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to define a user control for the context menu. Instead, declare it in a common resource dictionary (e.g. in App.xaml). Then you can access the context menu via `StaticResource`:

In App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu">
        ...
    </ContextMenu>
</Application.Resources>
```

In the window:

```
<Button x:Name="conbut" ... ContextMenu="{StaticResource contextMenu}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

just define it as you Window Grids `ContextMenu`, 
you don't need the button, any rightClick on the Grid space will open the `ContextMenu`

```
 <Window x:Class="contextmenu1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dc="clr-namespace:contextmenu1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
     <Grid>
       <Grid.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu x:Key="contextMenu">
                 ...
          </ContextMenu>
       </Grid.ContextMenu>         
   </Grid>    
  </Window>
```